# how to give admin password to solr admin panel

Tags: solr

I'm using solr search engine in my project. I want to protect solr's admin panel with username and password for any security issue. But I don't know how to do it. Is there any method for this?

Comment: Yes, Did you enable Solr authentication and authorization plugins?  https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html

Comment: @Vinay Ok, I did it with Basic Authentication now I have a problem which connecting my solr core with SolrJ. The error is like this **org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/adminCore: Expected mime type application/xml but got text/html. <html>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask Solr to enable one of the available Authentication and Authorization plugin. Here is official doc to refer:- https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html

One you have enabled your authentication/authorization plugins, you may also need to update all your clients to provide the required credentials(depends on type of the authentication plugin and your access control configurations).

For Example, If you have chosen Basic authentication plugin and if you are using SolrJ, you can do the following:-

```
SolrRequest req ;//create a new request object
req.setBasicAuthCredentials(userName, password);
solrClient.request(req);
```